configuring internet access through other server
I have server A which has a 4-port Network Interface Card, and it is configured to reach the internet via its eth0 where DNS and a gateway and a proxy is specified.
I have an identical server B with static ip address 192.168.1.2 and I only connect its eth1 port to server A's eth1 port (where server A eth1 has static ip 192.168.1.1).
How in Linux, RHEL-8.10 specifically, do you configure networking to give server B internet access via (through) server A?
As an admin I need a test system (server B) that I can blow up and reboot without affecting users on production server A.  But I need internet access on server B to do basic yum install stuff conveniently.

Why do you not want to connect server B to the network normally? What is the benefit of the approach you describe where you instead connect to server A?

it's a temporary need I do not want to go through the overhead for of getting formally on the network in a work environment, which would take 3+ months to happen and then still not work

Ah, OK. That might be worth mentioning in the question then although it seems like what you are asking for is a way to backdoor your work and get around the limitations. After all, if all you need is the ability to yum install stuff, wouldn't having a local repository work better? Or just downloading the rpms from serverA and copying to server B?
